# flutter iOS System decimal separation

Tags: ios, flutter

I know that in the iOS System the user selects a region that defines number and date format. The iOS Keyboard present the decimal separator character regarding the region selected. Eg. US separator is '.' and Germany separator is ','.

How can I discover which decimal separator the system is using?

My problem is that I have a region Germany and language English, then flutter NumberFormat is using one pattern and the keyboard is presenting another pattern.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57397259/flutter-ios-number-keyboard-decimal-separator/57496055#57496055